# Generating Google Function Chart with PHP Arrays data from MySQL, but function doesn't visualize

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, google-visualization

I want to create a function chart from Google Charts with my data coming from a MySQL database (localhost). The program shows no error, that is conflicting with this topic, when compiling with a online markup language validator, though it still doesn't create the function chart when viewing in the browser. I checked my code and online sources, including multiple posts on this topic from this forum, but to no avail.
The PHP code works for sure. The only thing i can think off straight away would be, that the JavaScript code is not loaded right.

The JavaScript part is a slightly modified version from sgoogle linechart (type function) sourcecode (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

Code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "daylight";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
        $startdate=time()-(time()%(24*3600))-7200;
        $enddate=$startdate+365*24*3600;
        //echo $startdate."<br>".$enddate;
        $s=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $startdate);
        $e=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $enddate);

        $Off = 12;  //Offset
        $A = 4;     //Amplidute
        $light=0;

        for($i=$startdate; $i<=$enddate; $i+=$day)  //genData (works)
        {...}

        $sql_request = "SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `Datum` >= '$s' And `Datum` <= '$e'";
        $daylight_array=array();
        $date_array=array();
        foreach($conn->query($sql_request) as $row)
        {
            $daylight_array[]=$row["Tageslicht"];
            $date_array[]=$row["Datum"];
            //print $row["Tageslicht"];
        }
        // echo json_encode($date_array);
        // echo json_encode($daylight_array);

?>
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    var date = <?php echo json_encode($date_array); ?>;
    var daylight = <?php echo json_encode($daylight_array); ?>;

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Jahr-Monat-Tag');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sonnenstunden');

        for(i = 0; i < date.length; i++)
            data.addRow([date[i], daylight[i]]);

        var options = {

          title: 'Sonnenstunden über das Jahr',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the generated source code, in particular the JSON? Are you getting any error messages in the browser's console? What if you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Where can i do that, in the browser or do i have to write this in the code, sorry for asking but i am relativ new to javascript?

Comment: `It stands so on the google code without the new, and they should know what is right.` jeesus isn't correcting Google, he's correcting *you*. Please double check the linked docs and your own code before getting defensive.

Comment: @ChrisG i checked console.log date and daytime, and both didn't have anything in them, also data doesn't output anything either.
That would mean the assignedment doesn't work, even though json_encode works when i echo it in php section.
Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: If you have changed the code, please put your current version in the question.

Comment: I opened now the Developerstool to see whats going on and i got this error message: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 11.0788 does not match type number in column index 1
    at gvjs_Io (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:119)
    at gvjs_Vba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:139)
    at gvjs_R.gvjs_.c_ (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:141)
    at gvjs_R.gvjs_.gq (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:142)
    at gvjs_R.gvjs_.fq (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:142)
    at drawChart (uebung.php:45)
So it doesn't like my numbers or how i have them?

Comment: most likely the data is coming across as string (`"11.0788"`) instead of number (`11.0788`), try using `parseFloat` to convert to a number --> `data.addRow([date[i], parseFloat(daylight[i])]);`...

Comment: That was also one Option that worked, though i used now JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK when transferring the numeric array into JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your method of initializing the DataTable is incorrect. As [the docs say](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable), `arrayToDatatable` creates and populates a DataTable using a single call. So instead, you should initialize the DataTable with something like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Didn't have the time to try it out, but seems to be this way....

If you insist on using the method you used, then provide the method with array of data as per documentation.

Comment: It stands so on the google code without the new, and they should know what is right.

Comment: I was looking at the docs also and I didn't find any place where they are giving misleading examples. Every place they initialize a new object, the `new` keyword is used as it should be. Methods like `arrayToDataTable` don't need the keyword.

Comment: @Andreas They use your version when they put the data right in the function call; however when they add columns and rows to an existing table, they use the line from this answer. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lr0oste8/

Comment: So date and daylight should be arrays or do i need to inilize them as arrays first?

Comment: Check [this example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#creating-material-line-charts) for the required changes. Your data is fine, but you need to fix the lines where the DataTable is created and drawn.

Comment: yeah so it works but it seems like, when i try to push the arrays with json_encode it doesnt work any longer

Answer (score 0):

First, arrayToDataTable seems to require a parameter to be passed.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
```

Second, date and daylight are not the right type. They are currently string when they are needed to be arrays.

```
var date = JSON.parse(<?php echo JSON.stringify($date_array); ?>);
var daylight = JSON.parse(<?php echo JSON.stringify($daylight_array); ?>);
```

After pushing those two updates it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: In JavaScript, no semi-colons are required. The issue here is completely unrelated to syntax.